# a simple getch() and strcmp problem

Tags: c++, c, string, getch

I have this simple problem that gets an input from the user using a function then checks if the input is 'equal' to the "password". However, strcmp would never return my desired value, and the culprit is somewhere in my loop that uses getch() to take each character separately and add them to the character array. I found this out by having printf display the character array. If I type in pass word, the function would display it as pass word ". I have no idea on why the closing double quote and a whitespace was included in the array right after the word I typed in. Any idea? Here's the code. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int validateUser();

int main()
{
   for(int x = 0;x<2;x++)
   { 
        if(validateUser())
         {   
             system("cls");
             printf("\n\n\t\t** Welcome **"); break; 
         }
        else                    
         {   
             system("cls");
             printf("\n\n\t\tIntruder Alert!");
             system("cls"); 
         }
   } 


    system("PAUSE>nul");
    return 0;
}

int validateUser()
{
    char password[9];
    char validate[] = "pass word";
    int ctr = 0, c;
    printf("Enter password : "); 
    do
    {
        c = getch();
        if(c == 32)
        {
             printf(" ");
             password[ctr] = c;
        }

        if(c != 13 && c != 8 && c != 32 )
        {
          printf("*");
          password[ctr] = c;
        }
        c++;    
    }while(c != 13);

    return (!strcmp(password, validate));
}
```

Comment: I see you have changed the array size. Please don't do that after you've received answers. Now my answer does not make sense.

Comment: You've also changed `c++` to `ctr++` this makes the answer by user @joshD completely useless. Please revert the changes.

Comment: sorry sir those are just typos, but I'll be reverting it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Your char array `password` does not
  have a terminating null char.
- You need to ensure that you don't
  stuff more than 8 char into
  `password`
- Also `c++` should be `ctr++`

.

```
do {
 // stuff char into password.
 ctr++; 
}while(c != 13 && ctr <8);

password[ctr] = 0;
```

Comment: oh, so do I have to explicitly add the /0 right after the user pressed enter sir?

Comment: Actually its `\0` whose value is `0` so you can assign `0`

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. Now I have completely understood. I thought the compiler would automatically put the 0, but now I know it isn't. Also, I have reverted the changes. Sorry for that sir.

Answer (score 2):

You're incrementing c in your loop. You should be incrementing ctr. Also, all the stuff everyone else has said (null terminator, only 8 characters, etc).

Answer (score 0):

`getch()` is a function defined in a non-standard header `<conio.h>`. Relying on non-standard features is not recommended when you want your code to be portable. :)

Comment: I am aware of that sir, but how would that information help me in any way?

Comment: It might prompt you to look for alternatives, either C style from `<stdio.h>`, or C++ style using std::cin's member functions.  Similarly, `'\n'` is a portable notation for a newline character, a good alternative to hardcoding ASCII 13 (the carriage return code, rarely used for this outside DOS/Windows).  Not a priority when you're just starting to learn coding though.

Answer (score 0):

```
do {
   // stuff char into password.
   ++ctr; 
   } while(c != 13 && ctr < 9);

password[ctr] = '\0';
```

Comment: It will be much better if you explain why your solution works and OP's one doesn't.